# FaceletException: The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "h:commandButton" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: jsf, brackets, commandbutton

I tried to create a command button with value `<<`.

```
<h:commandButton value="<<" />
```

However, it threw the following exception:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /test.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "h:commandButton" must not contain the '<' character.

How do I create such a button?

Comment: jsf version, facelets or jsp, what are the facelets configurations?

Answer (score 6):

```
<h:commandButton value="&#60;&#60;" />
```

- [Document](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/tlddocs/h/commandButton.html)

Comment: @vivek, try again, updated the answer.

Comment: The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "a4j:commandButton" must not contain the '<' character.
 This type error found

Comment: check update. I tested locally, its working

Comment: or choose any represent that java understands from [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c/index.htm)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi,Vivek This will work if the view is XML; these entities aren't interpreted in standard JSP syntax (at least, not in Glassfish)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a4j:commandButton value="&lt;&lt;"></a4j:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandButton value="&lt;&lt;"  action="#{myBean.action}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

**JSF** provides default button compponent called `h:commandButton value="<<" action="#{buttonController.action}"/>"`.

Here in action `buttonController` is the managed bean name and action is the method to call after clicking this button.

Comment: Why are you repeating an already given answer? If you agree an answer, just upvote it. This is a Q&A site, not an old fashioned discussion forum or something primitive.

Comment: @BalusC, thanx for the suggestion... I will consider this...

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi from now...